# Submitted value scope

Tags: jsf-2, scope, viewstate

I have a primitive view: a form containing a validatable text input component and a command button. The input value is pointing to a session-scoped backing bean.

I open the page, enter an invalid value and submit the form: after the postback, a validation error is appearing and the input component is displaying the submitted value which did not pass validation. The model value in my session-scoped bean is left intact, as expected.

Ok, now I open another tab in the browser and open the same page. To my surprise, *the input component is displaying the submitted value from the first tab*. I've been supposing the view state to be new at another GET request and the plain model value from my session-scoped bean to be shown instead.

If I use a view-scoped bean instead of a session-scoped one the model value is being rendered for the input component in the second tab, not the submitted value from the first tab.

Is the submitted value not the part of the view state and kept somehow along with the model? Or is its scope tuned up in some smart way depending on the referenced bean's scope?

Sorry in advance if this question is stupid but I will be very grateful for removing my misunderstanding.

Comment: Nope. The same ViewScope will exist within browser tabs. This is supposed to change in JSF2.2

Comment: @kolossus, Thank you for your reply. I thought it was session that is shared betweeb the tabs, not view. Every GET request is supposed to create a new view, regardless of whether it is a browser tab or not, isn't it? Could you please give some link to the related planned enhancement in 2.2 so that I can understand if we are talking about the same things.